# Nash cryptosystem

Tags: encryption, hardness-assumptions

In 1955, [Nash proposed a cryptosystem](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2012/files/H03-Cryptosystem-proposed-by-Nash.pdf) in a declassified handwritten letters sent to the National Security Agency. The letters also include a conjecture which is equivalent to the famous $P \ne NP$ conjecture. I am not an expert in cryptoghraphy and I want to know the encryption and decryption functions in modern language.

> What is the formal description of Nash's cryptosystem according to modern cryptography? What is the implicit hardness assumption used to provide security?

Update: [Shamir and Zinger](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2012/files/H03-Cryptosystem-proposed-by-Nash.pdf) published a paper that describes an efficient plaintext attack on Nash's cryptosystem (pointed out by @deviantfan).

Comment: Did you read the letters?

Comment: @deviantfan the letter predates modern cryptography and hence understanding it is very hard for me.

Comment: ... So binary numbers, addition, and the concept of permutation is hard? Well ... I find Nashs system much easier than any modern cipher.

Comment: @deviantfan Please go ahead and post an answer. As I said this is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things first:

- Even in 1955, Nash's encryption algorithm (I'll call it NEA) was rejected by the NSA because they deemed it not secure enough. So do not use it in real life.
- Like eg. AES, NEA is not based on any of the usual hard algorithms like factorization etc.

NEA is a symmetric stream cipher, ie. there's just one key for both encrypting and decrypting, and there's no minimum block size: One input bit becomes one output bit.

---

NEA needs one (possibly) public parameter, a key with several parts, and an IV (initilization vector) for each message.

The public parameter first:

- A natural number N, larger is better for security. 256 is a usual value.

A key consists of:

- Two random permutations P for N values. Ie. P[0][0] to P[0][N-1] are the numbers from 0 to N-1 but in some random order, and P[1][0] to P[1][N-1] too but in a completely different random order.
- Two random N-bit numbers, B[0][0] to B[0][N-1] and B[1][0] to B[1][N-1]

A IV is a random N-bit number just like B[0] or B[1] above.

---

Encrypting/Decrypting a message M with L bit to the ciphertext C, as pseudocode:

```
//N, P, B, and IV are given  
//S is a N-bit memory


Permut(X)
{
    R = S[P[X][N-1]]
    for all i from N-2 down to 0
    {
        S[P[X][i+1]] = S[P[X][i]] xor B[X][i];
    }
    S[P[X][0]] = X
    return R
}

Encrypt(M,L)
{
    S = IV  
    C[0] = M[0] xor Permut(0)  
    for all i from 1 to L
    {
        C[i] = M[i] xor Permut(C[i-1])
    }
    return C
}

Decrypt(C,L)
{
    return Encrypt(C,L)
}
```

Comment: Nice. Can you comment on possible weaknesses against attacks?

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany Eg. a chosen plaintext attack in `O(N^2 log^3 N)`: https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/339.pdf